# Mozilla flexbox behavior different to webkit and ie

Tags: html, css, mozilla, flexbox

I try to realize a vertical list of items which wraps them on overflow and results in a horizontally scrollable list. I want to use flexbox to achieve this.

Webkit and IE produces the expected output. Not so Firefox. Please see this Example:

[JSFIDDLE Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/alexander_genne/LmjnN)

```
    <div class="listbox flex-direction-vertical flex-wrap">
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
    <div class="listitem"><div class="tablediv"><table><tr><td><div class="content">content</div></td></tr></table></div></div>
  </div>

BODY 
{
    counter-reset: listitem; /* Create an item counter scope */
}
.content:before {
    content: "item " counter(listitem) ". ";
    counter-increment: listitem;  /* Add 1 to listitem */
}
.listbox
{
    height: 400px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    overflow:auto;

    /* old syntax */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;

    /* new syntax */
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: -moz-flex; 
    display: -moz-flexbox;
    display: -o-flex; 
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox; 
    display: flexbox;
    display: flex; 
}
.flex-direction-vertical
{
    /* old syntax */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-align:start;
    -moz-box-pack:start;

    /* new syntax */
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -moz-flex-direction:column; 
    -o-flex-direction:column; 
    -ms-flex-direction:column; 
    flex-direction:column;

}
.flex-wrap
{
    /* old syntax */
    -webkit-box-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-box-wrap: wrap;

    /* new syntax */
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap:wrap; 
    -o-flex-wrap:wrap; 
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.listitem
{
    background-color:green;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
.content
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Please help me to find a solution for Firefox.

Thank You in advance
Alex

Comment: It would be a good idea to order your properties in order of oldest version to current version (box -> flexbox -> flex).  Also, IE is following the spec using `-ms-flexbox` as the display property, while older FF is using `-moz-box`, and Opera never used prefixes, so you've got quite a few properties you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at a Firefox before version 20, then you're out of luck.  Those FFs follow the specification from 2009 and the property that controls wrapping is called `box-lines` (single|multiple).  Only trouble is, they never implemented it:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=562073

Good news is that starting with version 20, FF will be following the September 2012 specification.  I haven't followed their progress, but caniuse is marking it as being fully "supported" in those versions rather than just "partially supported".

Comment: Thank You, i tried out this on the nightly version of Firefox, same behavior. Do You know another approach to realize vertical wrapped list which works cross browser? I already tried to use the multicolumn feature, but ended up with a scrolling problem on webkit browsers. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984085/css-column-layout-using-position-relative-breaks-scrolling-on-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: I was going to suggest using `columns`, but that's an unfortunate bug.  The only thing I can recommend is to go with either flexbox or columns and not supply prefixes for the offending browser.  Your elements are all a fixed size, so you could just float them or use inline-block as a fallback.

Comment: Ooh the fixed size was for demo only. I think about implementing the arranging of the items by myself making them absolute positioned. This would have many advantages. The only thing is the possible size change in case of internal image loaded etc. Is there a way to get informed on size changes, or is the only way to compare the values every 1 msec like jquery mutate does? This could become very expensive. Especially on mobile devices, or?

Comment: If the primary contents are images, you could make the flex item element containing it a fixed width.  If the browser supports flexbox, it will ignore the width value completely and just go with instructions from the `flex` property.  Browsers not supporting flexbox would be floated/inline-block with the fixed with.  Add `max-width: 100%` (and maybe `height: auto`) to your images and it should be perfectly contained.

Comment: The result will be a list control with orientation and wrap mode. The content of the list item is unforseeable. Horizontally oriented wrap mode i already realized using inline-block. What i need is a cross browser way for vertical wrap mode. Actually it gives the Impression that using flexbox or multicolumns from css3 is too risky. Another Approach could be to arrange the items manually by giving them an absolute Position. The only Problem could be that they become resized after this Rendering in case of Images for example. I could manage this by a timer -> dimension changes. Another idea?